# 'mawkish' : What semantic notions underlie 'maggots' with 'sentimental in an exaggerated or false way'?

Tags: etymology

> [mawkish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mawkish)  {adjective} = expressing or sharing emotion in a way that is exaggerated or embarrassing
>   SYNONYM[:] sentimental

[mawkish (adj.) on Etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mawkish&searchmode=none)

> 1660s, "sickly, nauseated" (a sense now obsolete),
>   from Middle English *mawke* "maggot" (early 15c.; see [maggot](https://www.etymonline.com/word/maggot)), but the literal sense of "maggoty" is not found. 
>   Figurative meaning "sickeningly sentimental, insipid" is recorded by 1702.

I accept that (the mere thought of) maggots can sicken or nauseate, but how did the notion of 'sickly, nauseated' shift to mean sentimentality? 
[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115233?redirectedFrom=mawkish) doesn't expound.

Comment: Observe that it's a progression.  The meaning was "maggot", then, a couple of hundred years later, "nauseated", then a hundred years after that, "falsely sentimental".  Surely the intermediate connections are obvious.  There is no law that says that the initial and final (to present) meanings must align.

Comment: @HotLicks well only 40 years, but the idea is there.

Comment: Try this:  (as a way to remember) Imagine that you go on a blind date that is an absolute nightmare, and you never speak to the person again, and one year later they call you up to say, "Hi darling, it's our anniversary!"  That would be mawkish AND would probably make you sick to your stomach.

Comment: Irrational sentiment is a powerful force in the development of word meanings.

Comment: Some people view rational thoughts as good mental meat, and sentimental opinions the mental maggots that ruin it!

Comment: I'm not sure why OxfordDictionaries have added _exaggerated_ to _mawkish_ because _sentimentality_ already includes _exaggerated_ so _mawkish_ seems to just be _sickeningly sentimental_ compressed into a single word.

Comment: Although I'm generally interested in etymological questions, I find it difficult to understand what you are looking for when you ask questions like "what semantic notions underlie [a shift in meaning that some word has undergone]? Are you simply asking for a historical explanation of why the meaning of this word changed from one thing to something seemingly quite different? Or are you asking far a mechanistic explanation of how words like the one of interest here sometimes undergo retrospectively surprising transformations in meaning?

Comment: @SvenVargs I'd like to know both please!

Comment: I don't know how many people here are devotees of the BBC radio-soap *The Archers*. (It has been running in the same 15-minute slot for 70 years!). This week, one of the characters, celebrating his 18th birthday, was given by his aunt, a recorded message made by his late-mother when he was 4 years old - for him to receive on his 18th birthday. It was played on air, and I described it to my wife as "mawkish", but she was not entirely in agreement. So mawkishness is clearly in the eye of the beholder.